# libwallycore error installing LND on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network-daemon

I'm setting up an LND node on Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed python3, and cloned the repo. I ran configure, and get this error on the make command:

```
checking byteswap.h, usability... no
checking byteswap.h, presence... no
checking for byteswap.h,... no
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking whether cc is Clang... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking whether more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
checking asm/page.h usability... no
checking asm/page.h presence... no
checking for asm/page.h... no
checking for python... no
configure: error: Cannot find python in your system path
external/Makefile:51: recipe for target 'external/libwally-core/src/libwallycore.la' failed
make: *** [external/libwally-core/src/libwallycore.la] Error 1
```

I've searched online but I couldn't find anything helpful to get past this. How can I solve this and get LND installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: type `whereis` python in your shell and see if it is on `$PATH`. If it isn't, then there's something wrong with your ubuntu distribution since ubuntu typically ships python. You could try to re-install python by putting in `sudo apt-get install python` in your shell.

Comment: Looks, like you installed python3, but somehow softlink `python` was not created.
You may try to make the link yourself. Type `sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/bin/python`. This will create a link called "python" to python3.
However be sure, that python3 is needed for LND, otherwise just install python from apt-get.

Comment: None of tips above worked for me, unfortunately.